# Can Keras embedding layer give random vector for a certain index (e.g: -1) instead of a fixed vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, keras-layer, word-embedding

I have a problem where I have texts ( that can be very long max ~9000 words) that I need to embed with Keras Layer. I choose the fixed size 5000 for every text and I need to pad each sequence to get to the right shape. The classical way is to use Keras' pad_sequence that take as input list of lists of indexes and pad with zeros or cut the lists of indexes to 5000. 
For my downstream task, I use a sort of convnet inspired by Kim's Paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5882). My concern is that the network learns in a certain sense the Wordcount by detecting the pattern of vectors that embed the 0 I used to pad the sequences. I am not saying that this feature is not important but I would like to force the network to learn other features in preferences. I was thinking about two things, first using an additional task (like an adversarial task) that take the latent representation created by the model before the output and use a branch of the model to predict the size of the text or a cluster of size, for example :

```
[,1000 words] -- cluster 1
[1001,2000words] -- cluster 2
 ect..
```

Then use the output to encourage the network to map other information in the latent space by adding an adversarial loss to the main loss term. My other idea was instead of using zeros' vectors to pad the embed the zero paddings, we could use random vectors, generated on the fly while training. (every time the network sees a particular index, for example -1, it knows it has to generate a random vector). I was thinking that it breaks the symmetry introduced by using zeros vectors and helps the model to generalize better as it introduces noise in the training process.

As I didn't find any papers on this task of padding with something else than zeros, I turn to the community. What do you think? I went through the Embedding layer implementation and I am pretty sure that the implementation of the second idea is pretty straightforward in keras by changing the K.gather() by a flag for the right indexes (It would be longer execution time though).

Thanks in advance for your feedback and your ressources !